# Subistituir linha da tabela dinamica

Tags: jquery, table, objetos, índices

Na função pegar linha eu pego a linha clicada e envio os dados para o formulário e armazeno OBJ da linha e pego index tbm

```
var index = $(obj).closest('tr').find('td').eq('0').text();
```

Aqui depois que eu alterei os dados eu crio a tr e passo os dados para tabela, mas ele vai para final eu queria que substitui-se a linha que eu tinha clicado, to quebrando cabeça e não acho solução

```
 var tr =
    '<tr class="classeDaLinha">' +
    '<td class="id" id="id"  >' + id + '</td>' +
    '<td class="name">' + name + '</td>' +
    '<td class="qtde" >' +
    '<input style="width:50px;" type="number" name="quant[' + id + ']" id="quant[' + id + ']" class="p_quant" value="' + qtde + '"  onkeyup="updateSubtotal(this)" onchange="updateSubtotal(this)" data-price="' + price + '" />' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="num_modulos"> ' + num_modulos + '</td>' +
    '<td class="obs_item"> ' + obs_item + '</td>' +
    '<td class="price"> ' + price + '</td>' +
    '<td class="subtotal">' + subtotal + '</td>' +
    '<td><img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" title="Delete" onclick="excluirProd(this)"/>\n\
            <img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/edit.png" width="20" height="20" title="Editar" onclick="pegar_valor_linha_tabela_editar(this)"/></td>' +
    '</tr>';
$('#products_table tbody').append(tr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Com `remove` e `after`**

Uma forma de fazer o que pretende é remover o antigo e adicionar o novo no seu lugar. A remoção é feita com a função `remove()`, e após isso tem de adicionar com a função `after` para garantir que o novo `<tr>` fica a seguir ao `<tr>` anterior, ao contrário da função `append` que lhe adiciona como ultimo filho.

Exemplo de construção da sua função de click para remover:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    const tdRemover = $(this).closest("tr"); //obter o tr acima

    trRemover.prev().after(tr); //colocar o novo tr antes deste
    trRemover.remove(); //remover este tr
});
```

Naturalmente isto implica definir a classe `delete` na imagem que serve como clique:

```
... 
'<td><img class="delete" src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" title="Delete"/>....
<!--     ---------^class delete aqui, e sem o atributo onclick-->
n\<img class="edit" src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/edit.png" width="20" height="20" title="Editar"/>
<!--     ------^class edit aqui, e sem o atributo onclick-->
```

**Com `replaceWith`**

Outra solução ainda mais simples é utilizar diretamente a função `replaceWith` do Jquery que substitui o elemento selecionado diretamente pelo html recebido como parâmetro:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").replaceWith(tr); //substituição direta
});
```

**Com `html`**

Uma terceira solução passa por substituir o html do `<tr>` todo com o novo. Isso implica modificar o novo html para não incluir o proprio `<tr>`:

```
var tr =
    //sem o '<tr>' aqui no inicio 
    '<td class="id" id="id"  >' + id + '</td>' +
    '<td class="name">' + name + '</td>' +
    ...; //sem o '</tr>'; no fim
```

E a função de click seria:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").html(tr); //colocar o html como conteudo
});
```

Documentação para a função [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) e para [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda deu certo
       OBJ.prev().after(tr); //colocar o novo tr antes deste
       OBJ.remove();
       var contador = 1;
       $(".classeDaLinha").each(function () {
                 $(this).find("#id").html(contador);
               $(this).find(".p_quant").prop("name", "quant[" + contador + "]");
             contador++;
       });
       $(OBJ).closest('tr').show();
       $('#id').val('');

Comment: tem como vc da olhada nesta outra pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251275/pegar-os-valores-das-colunas-da-linha-clicada-e-passar-inputs

Comment: @JuniorRamoty Neste preciso momento não posso, mas mal possa olho para a pergunta, sim.