# Pegar os valores das colunas da linha clicada e passar inputs

Tags: jquery, table, tabela-html, índices, click

Aqui é a função para pegar o valor da linha da tabela, e passar para inputs, se eu pego as linhas que foram carregadas do banco não da erro mas quando, insiro um novo item na tabela, ai pego o valor da 2 coluna da linha, no teste    `alert` exibi normal texto mas quando passo para os inputs, os campos se misturam, nunca vi nada igual, o input descrição aparece com array dentro.

```
<br /><label for="resultDescricao">Descrição do item</label>
        <input type="text" id="resultDescricao" name="resultDescricao" readonly >

        <br /><br /><label>Modelo:</label>
        <input type="text" id="modelo" onchange="montarDescricao()" style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline-block" onkeyup="montarDescricao()">

        <br /><br /><label for="obs_item">Obs:</label>
        <input type="text" name="obs_item" id="obs_item" onchange="montarDescricao()" style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline-block" onkeyup="montarDescricao()">

        <br />
        <label for="obs" ></label>
        <input type="hidden" id="obs" name="obs">

        <br /><label for = "medida">Medida:</label>
        <input type = "text" id = "medida" onchange = "montarDescricao()"  placeholder="0,00" style = "text-transform: lowercase; display: inline-block" onkeyup = "montarDescricao()">

        <br /><br /><label for="bracoesq">Braço esq.:</label>
        <input type="text" id="bracoesq" onchange="montarDescricao()" style="text-transform: uppercase" onkeyup="montarDescricao()">

        <br /><label for="modulo">Módulo</label>
        <input type="text" name="modulo" id="modulo" onchange = "montarDescricao()" placeholder="2x0,00"style = "text-transform: lowercase; display: inline-block" onkeyup = "montarDescricao()">

        <br /><br /><label for="bracodir">Braço dir.:</label>
        <input type="text" id="bracodir" onchange="montarDescricao()" style="text-transform: uppercase"  onkeyup="montarDescricao()">

        <label for="revestimento">Revestimento</label>
        <select name="revestimento" id="revestimento" class="revestimento" onChange="montarDescricao()">
            <option value="">  Selecione um Revestimento</option>
            <?php foreach ($revestimento_list as $rl): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rl['id'] ?>"><?php echo $rl['nomedesc']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select><br />

        <br /><label for="vlr_unitario">Vlr. unitário</label>
        <input type="text" name="vlr_unitario" value="R$ 0,00" id="vlr_unitario" data-prefix="R$ " class="dinheiro" >

        <br /><label for="qtde">Qtde</label>
        <input type="number" name="qtde" id="qtde" onkeyup="so_numero(this)" value="1" min="1" >

        <br /><br /><label for="num_modulos">Qtde módulos</label>
        <input type="number" name="num_modulos" id="num_modulos"  value="2" min="1" />

        <input type="button" onclick="addProd()" id="add_prod" value="adicionar produto" style="background-color: #faac58"/>

        <br />
        <input type="text" name="json_prod" id="json_prod">
        <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
</fieldset>
</fieldset>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="products_table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nome do Produto</th>
    <th>Quant.</th>
    <th>Módulos</th>
    <th>Obs.</th>
    <th>Preço Unit.</th>
    <th>Sub-Total</th>
    <th class="acoes">Ações</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 function pegar_valor_linha_tabela_editar(elemento) {
var id = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('0').text().trim();  // recebe id  
var descricao = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('1').html();  // recebe descriçao completa
var qtde = $('input[name="quant[' + id + ']"]').val().trim(); // recebe quantidade
var num_modulos = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('3').text().trim(); // recebe numero de modulos
var obs_item = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('4').text().trim(); // recebe observacao
var vlr_unitario = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('5').text().trim(); // recebe valor unitario
OBJ = $(elemento).closest("tr"); //recebe objeto da linha

if (id === 0) {
    return;
} else {
    $('#id').val(id);

    //inicio quebra descriçao
    //aqui e coluna 2 da tabela eu pego e divico essas descrição
    var descricaoArray = descricao.split('[');
    var modelo = descricaoArray[0].trim();
    var medida = descricaoArray[1].trim();
    var bracoesq = descricaoArray[2].trim();
    var modulo = descricaoArray[3].trim();
    var bracodir = descricaoArray[4].trim();
    var revestimento = descricaoArray[5].split(']');

   //fim do quebra descrição

    $('#resultDescricao').val(descricao);
    $('#modelo').val(modelo); 
    $('#medida').val(medida.replace(']', ''));
    $('#bracoesq').val(bracoesq.replace(']', '').replace('BRE', ''));
    $('#modulo').val(modulo.replace(']', '')); 
    $('#bracodir').val(bracodir.replace(']', '').replace('BRD', '')); 
    $('#revestimento option:contains(' + revestimento[0] + ')').prop('selected', true);
    $('#obs_item').val($.trim(obs_item));
    $('#vlr_unitario').val(vlr_unitario.replace(' ', ''));
    $('#qtde').val($('input[name="quant[' + id + ']"]').val());
    $('#num_modulos').val(num_modulos);
    excluirProd(elemento);
}
```

}

**Modelo de descrição**

```
// CALIFORNIA [2,90] [BRE25] [3x80] [BRD25] [ARTIGO: 1.000 - COR: 02] - COM MAIS PUXES
```

**Quando da erro**

```
// 3 [CALIFORNIA [2,90] [BRE25] [3x80] [BRD25] [ARTIGO: 1.000 - COR: 02]] [BRE] [ 2] [BRD ] [ R$ 0,00]
```

**Campo medida**

```
// CALIFORNIA [2,90] [BRE25] [3x80] [BRD25] [ARTIGO: 1.000 - COR: 02]
```

Mesmo no `alert` exibindo que os dados estão sendo passados para os inputs corretamente, exibi tudo errado, nunca vi isso variável pegar valor sem ser declarado

Função para add produtos

```
function addProd() {
if ($('#modelo').val() === '') {
    alert('Informe um Modelo !');
    return;
}
if ($('#revestimento').val() === '') {
    alert('Selecione um Revestimento !');
    return;
}
if ($('#num_modulos').val() === '') {
    alert('Selecione a Quantidade de Módulos !');
    return;
}
if ($('#bracoesq').val() === '') {
    alert('Informe a medida Braço Esquerdo !');
    return;
}  
 if ($('#bracodir').val() === '') {
    alert('Informe a medida Braço Direito !');      
    return;
}
var products_table = document.getElementById('products_table');
var id = products_table.rows.length;
var name = document.getElementById('resultDescricao').value;
var price = document.getElementById('vlr_unitario').value.replace(/[ R|$|.]/gi, '').replace(/[,]/gi, '.');
var qtde = document.getElementById('qtde').value;
var num_modulos = document.getElementById('num_modulos').value;
var obs_item = document.getElementById('obs_item').value;

subtotal = price * parseInt(qtde);
subtotal = ("R$ " + number_format(subtotal, 2, ',', '.'));
price = ("R$ " + number_format(price, 2, ',', '.'));


incluir_produto();
document.getElementById('resultDescricao').value = "";
document.getElementById('modelo').value = "";
document.getElementById('vlr_unitario').value = 'R$0,00';
document.getElementById('bracoesq').value = "";
document.getElementById('bracodir').value = "";
$("#revestimento").val($("#revestimento option:first").val());
document.getElementById('qtde').value = "1";
document.getElementById('medida').value = "";
document.getElementById('modulo').value = "";
document.getElementById('obs_item').value = "";

if ($('input[name="quant[' + id + ']"]').length !== 0) {
    id = parseInt(id) + 1;

}

if ($('#id').val() != '') {              
   var tr =
   '<tr class="classeDaLinha" id="r'+id+'">' +
   '<td class="id" id="id"  >' + id + '</td>' +
   '<td class="name">' + name + '</td>' +
   '<td class="qtde" >' +
   '<input style="width:50px;" type="number" name="quant[' + id + ']" id="quant[' + id + ']" class="p_quant" value="' + qtde + '"  onkeyup="updateSubtotal(this)" onchange="updateSubtotal(this)" data-price="' + price + '" />' +
   '</td>' +
   '<td class="num_modulos"> ' + num_modulos + '</td>' +
   '<td class="obs_item"> ' + obs_item + '</td>' +
   '<td class="price"> ' + price + '</td>' +
   '<td class="subtotal">' + subtotal + '</td>' +
   '<td><img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" title="Delete" onclick="excluirProd(this)"/>\n\
           <img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/edit.png" width="20" height="20" title="Editar" onclick="pegar_valor_linha_tabela_editar(this)"/></td>' +
   '</tr>';
   OBJ.prev().after(tr); //colocar o novo tr antes deste
   OBJ.remove();
   var contador = 1;
   $(".classeDaLinha").each(function () {
             $(this).find("#id").html(contador);
           $(this).find(".p_quant").prop("name", "quant[" + contador + "]");
         contador++;
   });
   $(OBJ).closest('tr').show();
   $('#id').val('');           
} else {
    var tr =
    '<tr class="classeDaLinha">' +
    '<td class="id" id="id"  >' + id + '</td>' +
    '<td class="name">' + name + '</td>' +
    '<td class="qtde" >' +
    '<input style="width:50px;" type="number" name="quant[' + id + ']" id="quant[' + id + ']" class="p_quant" value="' + qtde + '"  onkeyup="updateSubtotal(this)" onchange="updateSubtotal(this)" data-price="' + price + '" />' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="num_modulos"> ' + num_modulos + '</td>' +
    '<td class="obs_item"> ' + obs_item + '</td>' +
    '<td class="price"> ' + price + '</td>' +
    '<td class="subtotal">' + subtotal + '</td>' +
    '<td class="acoes"><img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" title="Delete" onclick="excluirProd(this)"/>\n\
            <img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/edit.png" width="20" height="20" title="Editar" onclick="pegar_valor_linha_tabela_editar(this)"/></td>' +
    '</tr>';
$('#products_table tbody').append(tr);
}
updateTotal();
preencherJason();
}
```

Aqui requisição pra carregar os itens do banco e criar as linhas

```
function carregar_itens_pedido(id_pedido)
{
 $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: BASE_URL + '/pedidos/carregar_itens_pedido',
            data: {id_pedido: id_pedido},
            success: function (arrayRetorno)
            {                 
                $("#products_table tbody").empty();
                tr = "";
                for (var index in arrayRetorno) {
                    subTotal = arrayRetorno[index].vlr_unitario * arrayRetorno[index].vlr_unitario.qt;
                    id = arrayRetorno[index].id;
                    num_sofa = arrayRetorno[index].num_sofa;
                    name = arrayRetorno[index].nomedesc;
                    price = arrayRetorno[index].vlr_unitario;
                    qtde = arrayRetorno[index].qt;
                    num_modulos = arrayRetorno[index].num_modulos;
                    obs_item = arrayRetorno[index].obs_item;

                    subtotal = price * qtde;
                    subtotal = ("R$ " + number_format(subtotal, 2, ',', '.'));
                    price = ("R$ " + number_format(price, 2, ',', '.'));

                    if (qtde === null) {
                        qtde = '';
                    }
                    tr +=   '<tr class="classeDaLinha" >' +
                    '<td class="id" id="id">' + id + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="name">' + name + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="qtde" >' +
                    '<input style="width:50px;" type="number" name="quant[' + id + ']" id="quant[' + id + ']" class="p_quant" value="' + qtde + '"  onkeyup="updateSubtotal(this)" onchange="updateSubtotal(this)" data-price="' + price + '" />' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td class="num_modulos"> ' + num_modulos + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="obs_item"> ' + obs_item + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:100px;" class="price"> ' + price + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:100px;" class="subtotal">' + subtotal + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="acoes"><img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" title="Delete" onclick="excluirProd(this)"/>\n\
                    <img src="' + BASE_URL + '/assets/images/edit.png" width="20" height="20" title="Editar" onclick="pegar_valor_linha_tabela_editar(this)"/></td>' +
                    '</tr>';                           
                }
                $('#products_table tbody').append(tr);                                
                updateTotal();
                preencherJason();
             }
        });
      }
```

Comment: O melhor será mesmo criar um [exemplo mínimo verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) juntando algum html para que seja possível de testar e ver o problema em si. Veja [neste fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3REa548L8v) como o código que tem obtêm os valores dos `tds` funciona, assumindo que estão como html

Comment: Eu alterei aqui, mas o erro deve estar na hora de quebrar a descrição

Comment: Posta o HTML, asism fica mais fácil para simularmos aqui

Comment: Já postei o html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ramoty/971yLqpL/20/#&togetherjs=3REa548L8v @Isac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlw pela ajuda ai, o erro estava em um laço pra criar tabela que exibia os itens do banco já cadastrados, vou posta o código que usei pra solucionar.
FireDebug salvando novamente.

```
function pegar_valor_linha_tabela(elemento) {
var modelo = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('0').html().trim();
var medida = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('1').text().trim();
var bracoesq = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('2').text().trim();
var modulo = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('3').text().trim();
var bracodir = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('4').text().trim();
var revestimento = $(elemento).closest('tr').find('td').eq('5').text().trim();
$('#resultDescricao').val(modelo + ' [' + medida + '] [BRE' + bracoesq+ '] [' + modulo + '] [BRD' + bracodir + '] [' + revestimento + ']');
$('#modelo').val(modelo);
$('#medida').val(medida);
$('#bracoesq').val(bracoesq);
$('#modulo').val(modulo);
$('#bracodir').val(bracodir);
$('#revestimento option:contains(' + revestimento + ')').prop('selected', true);
var botao = document.getElementById("modulo");
botao.click();
}
```